Share nullable Guid column for nullable and not nullable properties in two models
I have a base model
public abstract class ExternalBicycle
{
  public Guid ShopId { get; set; }
}

and two implementations that share the same db table (table per hierarchy)
public abstract class LeasingBicycle : ExternalBicycle {}
public abstract class BicyclePurchase : ExternalBicycle {}

which worked fine but a new requirement came in that says the LeasingBicycle model must not require a value for the ShopId property.
While I can go for the solution with two separate columns (and I probably will have to do this), I'd like to see if it's possible to reuse one db column for both models. I tried making the ShopId property nullable in the shared model and then repeating this property for the BicyclePurchase model - public new Guid ShopId { get; set; } but it doesn't seem to work.
Is there any other way to achieve this?

You could perhaps leave it as is and assign some "magic" shopID if no shops were chosen, something like: Guid NONE_SHOP_ID = {00000...-000}

And perhaps define a mapping property public Guid? NullableShopId { set { ShopId = value ?? Guid.Empty; } get { return ShopId != Guid.Empty ? ShopId : null } } if needed elsewhere.

Thanks for the tips! I must admit I did not consider this approach because I don't like magic values so I think since there are no other thoughts, I'll just go for splitting this into two columns :( Thank you for your insight!
